Aligning long section names to the right side in the header
I'm trying to finish my thesis but I face some problems regarding text alignment in the header. I use the fancyhdr package and I want the chapter positioned on the left side and the section on the right side of the header. As I have some longer section names I tried following solution:
\newcommand{\changefont}{
    \fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
}

\fancyhf[lh,rh,ch]{}
\fancyhf[lh]{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\changefont 
\slshape\raggedleft\leftmark\qquad\raggedright\rightmark\\\\
\end{minipage}}

resulting in

Neither the first nor the second line of the section are aligned to the right. Another problem is that the second line colides with the horizontal line of the header.
I would like to have the section aligned on the right, and once it exceeds the center of the page, it continues on a new line.
I hope someone has an idee or even a solution.
Thanks,
Johannes

You can put the contents of \rightmark (i.e., section number and section title) into a minipage of width 0.5\textwidth.
A demo for your purpose:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
  {\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
  {\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\minipage[b]{.5\textwidth}\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont\slshape\raggedleft\rightmark\endminipage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\chapter{AAAAA}
\section{This section is very very very very very very very very long}
some text
\newpage 
some text
\newpage
\section{aaaa}
some text

\end{document}




Thank you so much! That is exactly what I am looking for.

The idea here is to adjust the width of the \parbox on the riight side to fit the remianing space.  Interestingly, the hard part was to always have the top of the header show up at the same level every time.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\lefthead}
\def\ps@myheadings{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}% assuming you want the page number somewhere
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
  \def\@oddhead{\savebox{\lefthead}{\slshape\leftmark}%
    \parbox[b][\headheight][t]{\textwidth}{\usebox\lefthead\hfill
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\lefthead-\columnsep}%
        {\raggedleft\slshape\rightmark}\par}}%
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
      \fi
      ##1}}{}}%
  \def\sectionmark##1{%
    \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
        \thesection. \ %
      \fi
      ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}

\chapter{AAAAA}
\section{This section is very very very very very very very very long}
some text
\newpage 
some text
\newpage
\section{aaaa}
some text

\end{document}

